# Is there a VS Code shortcut to copy the name of a file to the clipboard from the explorer view?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I often need to insert the name of a file from the explorer view in VS Code into a code file. Right now I right-click, choose "rename" from right-click context menu, double-click the file name, and then choose "copy" from the right-click context menu to copy it to the clipboard.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Same context menu: `Copy Path` or `Copy Relative Path`.

Comment: That's not very convenient as it copies the path along with the file, so you have to edit afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jack89ita.copy-filename) will achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to leave the question open for a day or so and see if any other ideas come in, if not I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: I know, I've tried looking for a native solution but regrettably there's none. This extension is handy though and does the job as VSC would be supposed to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree that the lack of native way is weird. There is already the "Copy" function in the menu, so I believe it's now a matter of processing the insert action at the receiving side - the editor - to get it pasted as a plain  filename. That's exactly how it works in WebStorm IDE.

Comment: Unfortunately after some testing I don't confirm that the extension really works on Ubuntu. It just does nothing,